# the library's API can't be used after I update gradle to 4.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle

After I updated Android Studio to 3.0,at the same time,I update gradle to 4.1。But,the library's API can't be used. Such as app module dependent on app1 module,then,app1 module dependent on app2 module,I can't use app2 module's API in app module。But，before gradle 4.1,it works。

Comment: Could please share gradle file for each of the module

Comment: Thank you.I solve it.It because that I change my compile to "compile project(path:':app',configuration: 'default')" in order to fix another bug. After I update gradle to 4.3.1,that bug was fixed,then I delete the "configuration: 'default'" ,this bug was fixed too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem after solve my error

> Error:Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :lp_messaging_sdk:
>     - debugApiElements
>     - debugRuntimeElements
>     - releaseApiElements
>     - releaseRuntimeElements

with the answer [#33](http://url.cn/5TXn13g").So,I update gradle to 4.3 and delete the "configuration: 'default'",then,my project built success